# Where is aspect-oriented programming?

Tags: aop

Some time ago AOP was going to be "the next big thing". I wonder if it has gained enough traction in big projects or if it is still in the world of ideas.

What do you think?

Comment: I know there is and older question about this, but it's been more than a year since then...

Comment: Subjective / Argumentative and not marked as community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AOP has its appliances, but I think it is a bit far-fetched to consider it as 'the next big thing'.
It's not like AOP replaces OOP for instance; IMHO, AOP is complementary to OOP.
For me, I see usages for AOP in cross-cutting concerns like logging, security, etc...  In some cases AOP helps you building/developing your infrastructure.

A while ago, I've been playing around with AOP a little bit (using PostSharp) (see: http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html).
It really helps you seperating some 'infrastructure concerns' from your main business-logic, which keeps you focussed on your businesslogic, without having to think on your infrastructure.

Comment: So AOP could be a good answer to singletons and static classes?

Comment: Hmmm, No. singletons and static classes have their usages to.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's used in a lot of projects already, but probably without the developers knowing it. for example, if you are using Spring's declarative transaction management (@Transactional annotation). spring uses aspects behind the scenes.
i think this kind of stuff will never be the next big thing, but it can definitely enhance the maintainability of a project.